# how to display files that are not user writable?

Tags: linux

In linux how can I list the ordinary files in current directory that are not user writable?
I tried with the ls -l command.But it displayed both the owner and group files.Is there a command to display this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -writable -ls
```

The parameters:

- `-maxdepth 1`: `find` is recursive, this limits results to the current folder and its children
- `-type f`: Only return files (not folders or links)
- `! -writable`: Only return those that aren't writable *to the current user*.
- `-ls` Don't just return the file names, but mimic `ls -l` output.

---

Alternatively, if you don't care about owner and group and the current user, just about the permission bits:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -perm -200 -ls
```

- `! -perm -200` returns those that do *not* have all of the set permission bits in `200` set (i.e. user-writable).

Comment: @subhashini You're welcome. To accept this answer as correct and mark the question as solved, click the check mark next to this answer.